# How to brute force decrypt wallet password ?

Tags: wallets, password, encryption

I have forgot my wallet password, but have an idea what it could be. I need to put a script together to try a long list of possible password.

What is the command to use for that, if I am to put it in bash or pythong script ? or is there a tool to use ?

This tools did not works, looks like it is outdated. 
https://github.com/burjorjee/pyethrecover

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I recover or reset a lost wallet password?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-can-i-recover-or-reset-a-lost-wallet-password)

Comment: The code mentioned in that question is out of date.