# Metamask to Private ethereum communication issue

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, metamask, golang

When i connect to my private ethereum network using the 'Custom RPC' of the metamask, **it is getting connected from the MetaMask**. FYI, i am connecting from outside the network of my server, and all necessary ports are open.

But the problem is the account information and the account balance of the Private ethereum network is not getting reflected in the MetaMask wallet.

**Q:** Do i need to import any seed phrase associated with the Private ethereum network on my MetaMask wallet?

If answer is yes, where can I find the seed pharase on the private ethereum network.

If answer is no, what do I need to do, to get the account numbers and balance reflected to my Metamask wallet?

Comment: Thank you for the thread, i followed the steps mentioned above, however while generating the privat ekey using keystore file i am getting the error as below, as the setup is on ubuntu, i created keystore file manually by coping the contents..is there a way to generate this private key on ubuntu directly? Regarding the error i entered the same passphrase which i had provided while creating the account. But still it shows invalid. please guide


(error_07) Please enter a valid password. Error: Key derivation failed - possibly wrong passphrase

Comment: I'd suggest to copy the file from your geth instance. You can list accounts files with `geth account list`.

Comment: the steps worked for other account, though it did not work for first account. Do i need to do the same things if i have multiple accounts. Is there any way i can do get the private keys for multiple accounts on private ethereum netowork

Comment: In my earlier comment, i have mentioned that i was not able to generate the private key for one of my account. Real case is, i lost my paraphrase for that account. How even the steps given works for other accounts.

Comment: To recover password look at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-can-i-recover-or-reset-a-lost-wallet-password