# Can the v2 keystore json file for Ethereum wallet be converted to v3

Tags: web3js, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, keystore

[image]

If someone has an Ethereum ICO keystore Json file like this pics, is it possible to convert it to the v3?

Answer (score 1):

There is the javascript library [ethereumjs-wallet](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet/blob/master/docs/classes/wallet.md) that allows to open various formats, EthSale between them and write a wallet in V3 format.

```
const { default: Wallet } = require('ethereumjs-wallet')

async function convert(str, pass) {
    const saleWallet = Wallet.fromEthSale(str, pass)
    const v3Wallet = await saleWallet.toV3(pass)
    console.log(v3Wallet)
}
```

Comment: I have been trying to use this but I have been getting an error: "TypeError: Wallet.fromEthSale is not a function". Any idea on why I get this? I am using node v15 and ethereumjs-wallet v1.0.1

Comment: @Etienne I fixed and tested the example to work with wallet from [unit tests](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-wallet/blob/master/test/index.spec.ts#L735-L742).

Comment: Hi @Ismael, 

Thanks for this. I have set this up, it works but it has not solved my problem. Actually, I am trying to brute force an ICO wallet because I have lost the password. I am now looking for any tool which can help me brute force the password

Comment: @Etienne That's a different question see if this can help you https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97/how-can-i-recover-or-reset-a-lost-wallet-password

Comment: Pyethrecover is not working for me. I will keep trying with hashcat, it seems to be more robust.